# Google charts - misaligned values on haxis

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using ng2-google-charts package, which is angular 2 and above wrapper for google charts, for a project. I have a column chart with months statistics.

[image]

The bar contains items for July, but it is misaligned from the value on the haxis.

The data is filled dynamically and looks like this:

[image]

It represents the statistics for last 12 months from the current month.

How can I align the bar at middle above the Jul 2017 value on the haxis?

Comment: use a string vs date for the x-axis...

Comment: yep, that solved the problem. :) Thanks!